# Using ADF, how do I extract specific rows based on variable header value?

Tags: csv, azure-data-factory, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a CSV file (if you can even call it that) that looks like this:

```
Client Data,,,,,
From Date: 26-Feb-2021 To Date: 26-Feb-2022,,,,,
CustomID: BLAH-BLAH,,,,,
,,,,,,
col1,col2,,,,
1,asdfasdf,,,,
{bunch more rows}
342324234,ff,,,,
,,,,,,
,,,,,,
,,,,,,
Client Data - Details,,,,,
From Date: 26-Feb-2021 To Date: 26-Feb-2022,,,,,
CustomID: BLAH-BLAH,,,,,
,,,,,,
Account Number,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
1,a,bc,def,ghi,2022-01-11
{bunch more rows}
333331,a,bc,def,ghi,2022-01-12
,,,,,,
,,,,,,
,,,,,,
Client Data - Crap,,,,,
From Date: 26-Feb-2021 To Date: 26-Feb-2022,,,,,
CustomID: BLAH-BLAH,,,,,
,,,,,,
Useless Column,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
1,a,bc,def,ghi,2022-01-11
{bunch more rows}
333331,a,bc,def,ghi,2022-01-12
```

How do I "window" in ADF where the header and rows that I want start from `Account Number,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6` and end until `333331,a,bc,def,ghi,2022-01-12`?

Mind you that this row `Account Number,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6` can appear anywhere or nowhere in the file.

Comment: Could you please provide input columns and expected columns?

Comment: I just want to search the file and look for a column called `Account Number` and pull all the rows after it until there’s no data (Null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I "window" in ADF where the header and rows that I want start from `Account Number,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6` and end until `333331,a,bc,def,ghi,2022-01-12`?

To achieve this, you need to use several transformations along with "window" transformation as below:

1. Here first I took sample dataset as you provided.

[image]

2. Then I took derived column and **created 3 columns dummy, FindACC (to find Account Number row) and FindNull(find null rows)**

```json
dummy - 1
FindACC - iif({_col0_}=='Account Number', '1', toString(null()))
FindNull - iif(isNull({_col0_}), '1', toString(null()))
```

[image]
Data preview:
[image]

3. Take Surrogate key transformation and **create rownum column with start and step value as 1.**

[image]

4. Now take window transformation with below settings

[image]
[image]
Create window column as below.

```json
FindACC - coalesce(FindACC, last(coalesce(FindACC), true()))
```

[image]

5. Then using Filter Transformation filter all rows with `FindACC == '1'`

[image]

6. Now take another window transformation with same settings as above just change window column as below

```json
FindNull - coalesce(FindNull, last(coalesce(FindNull), true()))
```

[image]

7. Then using another Filter Transformation filter all rows with `FindACC =='1' && isNull(FindNull)`

[image]

8. Now using select transformation remove all column which we crated, and you will get results as below.

[image]

Comment: Amazing.  I was stuck on this for a minute but after some preliminary testing, this looks to fit the bill.  Thanks a ton!